# binomial coefficient aproximation

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I found this aproximation

$$
\binom{n}{k}\sim \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$

But there was a note that said this holds just when $n>>k$, why is this? I need to consider this binomial coefficient when $k$ is near of $n/2$ and I would like use this or any similar expression to avoid some factorials.

Comment: Use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to use, but I just want to know if I can reduce the factorial expressions in order to have less Stirling's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the coefficient as $\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots (n-k+1)}{k!}$ When $n \gg k$ the numbers you subtract from $n$ in the numerator may be too small to matter.  If you ignore them you get the approximation $\frac {n^k}{k!}$  When $k$ is near $\frac n2$ this is not a good approximation.  [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is quite accurate, leading to the approximation of the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $${2n \choose n} \approx \frac {4^n}{\sqrt {\pi n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Because when $k$ is *not* a lot smaller than $n$, it doesn't work. We see this, for instance, with $k = n$ where $\binom nk = 1$ but $\frac{n^k}{n!}\gg 1$.